# How to implement jump in Pygame without sprites?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm new to programming and to Python as well as Pygame. As such, I'm not yet comfortable with sprites in Pygame. I'm trying to make a game where a block jumps whenever the spacebar is pressed - similar to Mario.

My code doesn't work as desired because whenever the spacebar is pressed, the block incrementally moves up (I've added a gravity component), instead of "jumping".

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))


# fixed variables at the start
x_pos = 400
y_pos = 400
current_speed = 15

def jump_coords(y_position, speed):
    if speed >= 0:
        #to move up, reduce the y-coordinate
        y_position -= speed
    return y_position

game_exit = False

# main loop
while not game_exit: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_pos = jump_coords(y_pos, current_speed)
                # 1 represents gravity value
                current_speed -= 1

    rect_one = pygame.Rect(x_pos, y_pos, 10, 10)  
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, (255, 0, 0), rect_one)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I know that I have to somehow make y_pos keep updating in the while loop whilst `speed >= 0` but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the minimal changes to your code to get the block to bounce:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

# fixed variables at the start
x_pos = 400
y_pos = 400
x_old = x_pos
y_old = y_pos
current_speed = 15

def jump_coords(y_position, speed):
    # to move up, reduce the y-coordinate
    y_position -= speed
    if y_position > 400:
        y_position = 400
        global jump_flag
        jump_flag = False
        global current_speed
        current_speed = 15
    return y_position

game_exit = False
jump_flag = False

# main loop
while not game_exit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                jump_flag = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                exit(0)

    if jump_flag:
        x_old = x_pos
        y_old = y_pos
        y_pos = jump_coords(y_pos, current_speed)
        # 1 represents gravity value
        current_speed -= 1

    rect_old = pygame.Rect(x_old, y_old, 10, 10)
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, (0, 0, 0), rect_old)
    rect_one = pygame.Rect(x_pos, y_pos, 10, 10)
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, (255, 0, 0), rect_one)
    pygame.display.update()
```

The most important changes was the removal of the check for speed greater than zero. The speed has to go negative if the block is going to come back down. The next change was to save the old x and y coordinates so that we can draw a black square over the old position. I also made it possible to exit the program by pressing the Escape key.

Answer (score 0):

I made this from scratch, I hope it's not too daunting!

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

tm = 20 # Terminal Velocity
gravity = 1

class Player:
    def __init__(self,speed,x,y):
        self.speed = speed
        self.x = x; self.y = y
        self.yVelocity = 0
        self.xVelocity = 0
    def getKeys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.xVelocity -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.xVelocity += self.speed

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if isGround(self.x,self.y):
                self.yVelocity -= 20

    def move(self,dt):
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 0
        if self.x > 800-15:
            self.x = 800-15
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0
        if self.y > 800-10:
            self.y = 800-10
        self.x += self.xVelocity
        self.y += self.yVelocity
        if self.xVelocity != 0:
            self.xVelocity /= 70*dt

        if self.yVelocity < tm and not isBlocking(self.x,self.y+self.yVelocity):
            self.yVelocity += gravity

        if isBlocking(self.x,self.y):
            self.yVelocity = 0

    def draw(self):
        screen.fill((255,0,0),(self.x,self.y,10,10))

def isBlocking(x,y):
    if x < 0 or x > 800 or y < 0 or y > 800:
        return True
    elif y >= 400:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isGround(x,y):
    if y >= 400:
        return True
    else:
        return False

player = Player(1,400,400)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    dt = clock.tick(60)/1000 # limit to 60 FPS.
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

    player.getKeys()
    player.move(dt)
    player.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Hope it helps!